# If `this` is not const, why can't I modify it?

Tags: c++, this-pointer

In *The `this` pointer* [class.this], the C++ standard states:

> The type of `this` in a member function of
>   a class **`X`** is **`X*`**.

i.e. `this` is not `const`. But why is it then that

```
struct M {
    M() { this = new M; }
};
```

gives

```
error: invalid lvalue in assignment  <-- gcc
'=' : left operand must be l-value   <-- VC++
'=' : left operand must be l-value   <-- clang++
'=' : left operand must be l-value   <-- ICC
(source: some online compiler frontends)
```

In other words, `this` is not `const`, but it really is!

Comment: keyword `this` is not a variable, therefore we can not state that it is constant or not.

Comment: even if this would work then you only have constructed an endless loop.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch: Either that or infinite recursion (like you can do in python). This wasn't the question, though.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Because in the same paragraph, it is also mentioned that `this` is a `prvalue` ("pure rvalue").

Examples mentioned in the standard for pure rvalue are the result of calling a function which does not return a reference, or literals like `1`, `true` or `3.5f`. The `this`-pointer is not a variable, it's more like a literal that expands to the *address of the object for which the function is called* ([class.this]). And like e.g. literal `true` has type `bool` and *not* `bool const`, `this` is of type `X*` and *not* `X*const`.

Comment: @busy_wait In C++, values have a *type* and a *value category.* The type of `this` is `X*`, its value category is prvalue. How is this non-inituitive? `this` has to be a prvalue (`&this` makes no sense) - why make its type `X * const` when it's unmodifiable already?

Comment: @Angew: One would have to add that there are languages where `this` (or its equivalent) isn't unmodifiable. E.g. python: `class X:
    def __init__(self): self = X()
s = X()` <-- This will give a `maximum recusion depth exceeded` and not a compile error.

Comment: So clear and concise +1. I understand c++ more now :) (mainly the explanation of pure rvalues).

Comment: Why does `&this` make no sense? What is the advantage of this method of passing `this` over passing it explicitly as a pointer, beyond cleaner code, of course?

Comment: @busy_wait `this` is a "pointer to the current instance." What would you expect the address of such a pointer to be?

Comment: Somewhere on the current stack frame. I'm guessing this is also the actual mechanism of transmission of the data, right?

Comment: @busy_wait: No. It's formally unspecified, but e.g. MSVC++ uses the `ECX` register. You can´t take the address of a register.

Comment: @MSalters Very well, that's the kind of answer I was looking for.

Comment: @busy_wait: As phresnel said, there are languages that allow you to modify the this pointer. Objective-C, for example. And it also make very good use of that, because this freedom (along with some others) make it possible for an abstract base class to silently provide instances of its subclasses, exchanging the object as it is initialized. Perfect for implementation hiding. Or for a constructor to return an already existing object, ensuring equivalence of identity and equality, etc. I had a case myself where I'd been glad to be able to do such tricks in C++, but alas, it's not going to be...